# Need a jquery closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, closures

Hi I create a jquery plugin, it's working but I hope that I need a closure to call an element.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/luiggi/uamL7/8/show  -  fullscreen
JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/luiggi/uamL7/8/   -  edit view

I call the function like this:

```
$('.mydiv').click(function(){
   $('table').addStylesTable({OwnClass:'christian'});
});
```

And this is my function:

```
$.fn.addStylesTable = function(options) {

    var defaults = {

        tablestyle: 'table',
        tableHover: true,
        table100: true,
        table50: false,
        table33: false,
        NewClass: true,
        OwnClass: 'reverse2'

    };

    var options = $.extend({

        OwnClass: 'reverse'

    }, defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
        if (options.tableHover == true) {
            alert(options.OwnClass);
            $('table').addClass(options.OwnClass);
        };

    });
};
```

If in the future somebody needs to call to this function for other element, they will need to duplicate this function, or write some if, case, switch....

I would like to call it like this:

```
  $('div').addStylesTable({OwnClass:'christian'}); // to modify the <div>
  $('p').addStylesTable({OwnClass:'christian'}); // to modify the <p>
```

Somebody knows, How can I do this?

Thanks, Christian

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is or what you want but it doesn't make much sense the way it's done. The plugin executes `$('table').addClass` in the end so it does not matter what element you call it on, it will act on all `<table>`s in the DOM...

Comment: I would like to use `$('table').addClass`, and 'table' use it like a parameter, I'm trying to explain my issue, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, just I need to change this line:

```
$('table').addClass(options.OwnClass);
```

for this one:

```
$(this).addClass(options.OwnClass);
```

And now I can use the functions like this:

`$('div').addStylesTable({OwnClass: 'christian'});` or `$('body').addStylesTable({OwnClass: 'christian'});` etc...

Thanks a lot, Christian